# WordPress Add/Edit Post right admin sidebar change title

Tags: wp-admin, taxonomy

How is it possible to change the "Tags" title on the right admin sidebar "accordion" and in the preferences of the block editor? See screenshots.

I've tried changing $wp_taxonomies['post_tag'], it did not help.

[image]
[image]